# JavaScript Error - Cannot set property 'textDecoration' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a click event for my button to change the text decoration I keep getting this error under the **done** event listener.

This is my code-

```
let li = document.createElement('li');
let rmv = document.createElement('button');
let done = document.createElement('button');    
      
rmv.classList.add('remove-button');
done.classList.add('done-button');      
li.classList.add('li-item');
      
rmv.textContent = 'X';
done.textContent = '✔️';      
      
rmv.addEventListener('click', handleRemove);
      
done.addEventListener('click', function(){ 
  txt.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
})
```

Comment: So, what is `txt`? Speculation: [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](/q/10693845/4642212).

Comment: Error is pretty clear : `txt` variable is `undefined`.

Comment: @Flo No, that’s not what the error says. `txt.style` is undefined.

Comment: True, my bad :D btw as `txt` does not exists in that scope, it also is `undefined` hehe

Comment: @Flo Yes, `txt` does exist, the OP just didn’t show the relevant part of the code. If `txt` didn’t exist, the error would’ve been _“`ReferenceError`: '`txt`' is undefined”_. If `txt` was `undefined`, the error would’ve been _“`TypeError`: Cannot read property '`style`' of `undefined`”_.

Comment: I actually defined txt earlier `let txt = document.createTextNode(input.value);` 
 you can view the entire code here; https://codepen.io/kiva-gordon/pen/bGqaQxK

Comment: @KivaGordon A text node doesn’t have a style. Only elements have styles. Create a `<span>` instead: `const txt = Object.assign(document.createElement("span"), { textContent: input.value });`.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I have. This was a long time ago, so this was before I had my JavaScript gold badge and the close votes aged away long ago, probably. Not sure what the point of your comment is.

Comment: Interesting, this question popped up as a new(ish) question on the front page me.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Yes, because of the non-answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will fix it. It's better to utilize relative paths like this for dynamically created output. It gives you greater flexibility. To explain, `e` is the `event` of the click. The click listener always has a single argument `event`, and you can access the element that fired it with `event.target`. Then you find the closest 'li' container and apply the style to that. You can use the same logic to remove the element as well.

```
done.addEventListener('click', function(e){ 
  e.target.closest('li').style.textDecoration = "line-through";
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip it's working perfectly now, you're a life saver